# Getting error - "java.io.IOException: Premature EOF" in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am using JMeter 5.4.1, where I am using a HTTP request for Post API call. I am getting the error - "java.io.IOException: Premature EOF".

Keep-Alive is checked. Timeouts are also set to 60 Seconds. I am using single thread.

What is the solution to get raid of this?

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:102)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1936)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:530)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:296)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:567)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's the size of the response you get back from the server?
Are you able to replicate the same call in any other app like Postman and get a response?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong, looking into the error it seems that you're getting an incomplete response.

If you can successfully execute this API call using browser or other API testing tool like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) - make sure that JMeter sends the same [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

You can also [increase JMeter debug logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the change up, once done you can check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

And last but not the least try switching to `HttpClient4` implementation, the setting lives at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]